# why android service class stop after start by user but has null?

Tags: android, service, gps, location

i was using startservice and stopservice.

it's start button code.

```
intent = new Intent(myActivity.this, myService.class);
startService(intent);
```

and stop button code.

```
intent = new Intent(myActivity.this, myService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

startservice and stopservice it's good working.
but, startservice -> stopservice after -> startservice (so it's restartservice),
it's have already has value that first startservice when restartservice.

it's service code

```
            public class myService extends Service {
            private LocationManager mLocationManager;
            private LocationListener mLocListener = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public synchronized void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.d("GPS", ""+location.getLatitude+"/"+location.getLongitude);
                        }

        public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
            }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
 mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(Provider, INTERVAL_TIME, INTERVAL_DIST, mLocListener);

return Service.START_STICKY;

        }

        public void onDestroy() {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocListener);
        super.onDestroy();
        }
```

why gave me before mLocListener value when restartservice?
(i have some error with code when copy & paste. but it's good working when only start->stop.)

Comment: stop service will kill the service , So you wont retain the value anymore

Comment: @Arju ok i know that and i want it. but, it's retain before value gave me. i think it's cached data. when first startservice. it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

For GPS try using `mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation`